# UNIX send CR rather than LF

Tags: c, linux, windows, terminal, newline

I'm writing an application in C that communicate via Serial port between driver and computer.

When I was testing the application on Windows using termite 1.8 I added *Append LF* option and everything was OK. But when I run Linux and open putty or screen my driver didn't response.

So I had read about "end of line" topic. But after that I made a lot of changes on Linux it still didn't work.

The next step was getting each bit from Serial and when I type `help[ENTER]` I got:

- On Windows (Termite) "help" -> 0x68(h) 0x65(e) 0x6c(l) 0x70(p) **0x0a (CR: Carriage Return, U+000D)**
- On Ubuntu (using screen and putty result the same)
  "help" -> 0x68(h) 0x65(e) 0x6c(l) 0x70(p) **0x0d(LF:    Line Feed, U+000A)**

And my conclusion was that in my case is inversely than is described on Wikipedia (in case of these "standard" programs)

Finally my question: "Is possible to set putty/screen or maybe download other programs for Linux that have feature to manually set the sign of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key?"

Comment: The `stty` command has option `onlcr` to map NL to CR-NL (CRLF) on output.  You may be able to exploit that, but you have to worry about the terminal emulator too.  There are other related options such as `ocrnl` and `onocr` and `onlret` to investigate.  One of the original sardonic observations about Unix was "Unix is clever enough to mimic any other system, and other systems are dumb enough to believe it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux considers a New Line (= LF = 0x0A) as line delimiter. However, if you had a dumb terminal hooked up to a serial port and pressed the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key, it would send a `CR` (0x0D). Therefore, on normal serial input, when a `CR` is received, the driver replaces it with a `NL`.

In the other direction, when you print a `NL` to the serial port, Linux changes it to a `CR/LF` as this is what as dumb terminal wants. (This dates back to teletypes where the `CR` backed up to the beginning of the line but stayed on the line and the `LF` advanced to the next line.)

What you want to do on Linux is to set the terminal into "raw" mode. This can be done with the shell command `stty raw` or with termios, though I don't remember the options. This will turn off echoing, processing of backspaces, <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, all character translation. You will then have a raw pipe where what you send on one end is exactly received on the other.

Obviously, you'll need to do the same on Windows, though I don't know how.